# Does deleting /system/xbin/su prevent root access?

Tags: android, android-source

I built android marshmallow from source for my nexus 5 using the "user-debug" build configuration. As a result, the device is "rooted"

Is deleting /system/xbin/su enough to unroot the device ? I don't wan't any app to get root access.

EDIT: If i do:

```
adb root
adb shell
```

Then it seems that I am logged in as root. How do I unroot ?

Comment: instead of just choosing close, can you explain why you want to close ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing two type of roots.

The root you are getting from adb is calld unsecure boot, or debuggable kernel option.
This is set inside the default.prop file in the ramdisk, and used in the adbd binary.

The /system/xbin/su is just a root elevation binary which in your version also has the right configuration in SE-Policy.
Just deleting it will deny root for all the apps, but not for you when you debug using ADB.

If you want to disable root for yourself in adb, you can just compile as 'user' instead of userdebug or hack into the /system/core/adb binary.

Comment: Thats a good explanation - so i guess by deleting /system/xbin/su, any app I install cannot get root, which is what I'm hoping for. Is there any other file I need to delete to prevent apps from using root ?

Comment: No. Just delete the su binary and then get a root checking app to test it

Comment: so I guess what you're saying is, as long as the su binary does not exist on the device the problem is solved (since it seems that most root checking apps just look in multiple locations for the binary).